# Is there a safe way to refactor struct member order in c++

Tags: c++, refactoring, llvm-c++-api

The code which I write for my own consumption is usually very dependent on member ordering. But if I want to change the ordering of the members, well that's bad.

I like this order dependence because wherever the order appears again and again it is easy to memorize and makes the code considerably shorter.

Writing ten or more ctors to be order independent is of course important if you have interfaces that must be stable but the resulting ordering chaos of ctor parameters is terrible. Strong typing can help, but again, lots and lots of code.

Aggregate initialization with designators at least helps to not overlook order dependent code when refactoring but its not good enough to make this task something anyone would look forward to.

You could write a program using LLVM to do this refactoring, but this is not a trivial one day task. Has anyone done this already and open sourced? Are there other ways to do this safely?

Here is an example:

**Original file:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct X {
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main () {
    X x{1, 2};
    std::cout << x.a << ' ' << x.b << std::endl;
    // ok, prints "1 2"
}
```

**Badly modified file, because done manually**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct X {
    int b; // b is now before a
    int a;
};

int main () {
    X x{1, 2}; // wrong, should be x{2,1} because b is now first member
    std::cout << x.a << ' ' << x.b << std::endl;
    // BAD, prints "2 1" but should be "1 2"
}
```

Comment: Unclear to me what you want to refactorize... example might help. As a note, there is possible warning if constructor initializer list doesn't match members order if it is what you want.

Comment: @Jarod42. The initializer list is safe because of the warning as you say. I mean something like `aggregate x = {1,2,3}` that after reordering must be `aggregate = {3,2,1}`. The only safe way to do it is using designators or automate it.